# Disable user from typing in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have `input` and a `button`. On that button click, JavaScript should be triggered.
I need that input to be restricted from typing, pasting, deleting...

When I set `disabled` tag to it, JavaScripts that interact with it don't work.

```html
<input disabled type="text" value="NOT BE CHANGED">
<button>Trigger some javascript</button>
```

Try it on [JSiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5qoLmd3/)

How else can `input` be restricted from typing, pasting, deleting... but still be interactive with JavaScripts?

Comment: enable it, copy, then disable it again.

Comment: Have you tried the `readonly` attribute?

Comment: Also to set the value of a `<textarea>`, set the `value` property, not `textContent`.

Comment: May be do not to use textarea but a div/label instead. Otherwise blur on focus or transparent div above it.

Comment: @bestinamir I've tried to use paragraph but I need input for PHP script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="text" class="id-format" id="id-format" value="SHALL NOT BE CHANGED">
```

JQuery:
Call on your `<input>` id field with JQuery and use the `.prop()` function to set the `readonly` attribute to true.

```
$('#myID').prop('readonly', true);
```

Pure JS:
Call on `input` id and add setAttribute() function to add the `readonly` attribute and set it to true.

```
document.getElementById("id-format").setAttribute('readonly', true);
```

OR set your attribute inline within your `input` tag

```
<input type="text" class="id-format" id="id-format" readonly="true" value="SHALL NOT BE CHANGED">
```

The reason `disabled` does not work: If the element is disabled, it does not respond to user actions, it cannot be focused, and the command event will not fire. In the case of form elements, it will not be submitted. Do not set the attribute to true, as this will suggest you can set it to false to enable the element again, which is not the case.

`readonly` :
Type: boolean
If set to true, then the user cannot change the value of the element. However, the value may still be modified by a script.

JS Fiddle Here: https://jsfiddle.net/72g6hpfc/

info:

`disabled` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XUL/Attribute/disabled

`readonly` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XUL/Attribute/readonly

Comment: Thank you, very nice explanation and showed me all ways to do it.